# Qualtrics and Auto authentication

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

So, I feel like I'm really close to a breakthrough here but moving forward is going to require some help.

I have a survey, we will call it "test".
To get to the survey, you click a link that has your email included as a jscript passthrough (e.g., https://osu.az1.qualtrics.com/SE/?SID=SV_abcdefg&ID=john.doe@emailtest.com)

I want to autoauthenticate john doe against a panel.

What I mean by that is that I want to use an authenticator that doesn't require a person to enter any data, but uses the data in the URL as an authenticator. You would think this can't be done, but I've also learned that you can run javascript in the description field by looking at:

https://sites.google.com/a/cognitivescience.co/research-using-qualtrics/home/functions-capacities-in-qualtrics/using-qualtrics-as-a-personalized-web-service-with-the-authenticator

However, all that does is change the label for the field and doesn't actually authenticate. It does, however, process the next button. This suggests that if I can fill in the authenticator with the embedded data passed through the URL using JavaScript, I should be able to autoauthenicate.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Strange example; I don't see how it ever would have worked.  Anyway, if you add the embedded data field ID to your survey flow before the Authenticator, then you could put a script like the following in label field:

```
<script>Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function(){$$('.InputText').first().value="${e://Field/ID}";$('NextButton').click();});</script>
```

Comment: I ended up using:

<script>Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {  document.getElementById('QR~Authentication-FL_5~0').value = '${e://Field/ID}';  this.clickNextButton();  });</script>

Where ID was the embedded data authenticator and the QR~Authentication-FL_5~0 was the element id. Thoughts about which approach you think is better?

Comment: The approach I gave you is easier and better.  Ids can change between se and jfe.  The approach I gave just updates the first input field so there is no need to lookup and hard code the id.  Also, in general, it is better and easier to use prototypejs instead of native javascript. The Qualtrics this.clickNextButton() function executes $('NextButton').click() so they do the exact same thing except $('NextButton').click() is more direct.